# Using conditionals: Having trouble coding for the script to restart from the beginning

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am having trouble telling the pine script to restart from the beginning. Here's what I hope to do: if a condition is false, then the script runs again to check if it is true. If and when it is true, the script moves on to check the next condition. It is my intention to create several conditions that the script checks, and only when all of them are true, then the script alerts me of a buy signal. May I ask what your advise to me would be, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger re-execution of a script from within. See the [usrman](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#events-triggering-the-execution-of-a-script) for conditions that trigger the re-execution of a script.